# What's the differences between time in Physics and time in everyday use?

Tags: time

OK. This question might sound as not a good question, but the word 'time' is so confusing to me. I mean thermodynamics says time is the product of entropy. Relativity says time is relative. Quantum Mechanics says time doesn't exist, and that we can derive any given equation without involving time like Kepler's law. And I thought time measurement such as hour or second is just what we invented for conveniences on daily lives.

So are definition of time in Physics difference from time we associated in everyday life?

Comment: Where did you read that quantum mechanics says that time doesn't exist? I think you're misinterpreting or misrepresenting the wording.

Comment: Oh! I am sorry. I should have stated that more clearly. I asked one Quantum Mechanics Professor from Germany. He explained to me that reality is not a continuous flow of time. reality is a snapshot of present time similar to a video camera.

Comment: Well, if they taught you how to properly read a clock, then the definition of time in physics and normal life is exactly the same: it's what the clock shows. Your problem begins where you are mistaking predictions about the ordered series of clock data in different theories for "time".

Answer (score 2):

In layman use, across the world (ignoring time zones), someone who is walking observes the same time as you. In physics, however, that person has his/her own time, relative to that person. In classical thermodynamics, time is the same as layperson's time. It is just described in a different way. Quantum mechanics doesn't say that time doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

The oldest perspective is the philosophical one established by Aristote; modified by Mach and then Barbour

1. Time is an aspect of change (ie motion)

There is the mathematical perspective

2. Time when mathematically conceived is just a parameter in the equation.

This in fact has nothing to do with time - it's purely formal

Physically there are a couple of candidates for the arrow of time

3. The direction of increasing entropy
4. The direction in which the universe is expanding

Comment: Candidate 3 "The direction of increasing entropy" is not viable for a number of reasons.

Comment: See, for example, Hans Reichenbach's "The Direction of Time".

Comment: @hft: I wasn't claiming that they aren't without controversy...

Comment: So physically in a closed system with no losses like in a good billiard table there is no time? Or maybe you're referring to the way time is conventionally oriented (i.e. the sign is attributed), in which case I agree.

Comment: @real: where did I claim that? Motion is an *aspect* of time; not all of it.

Answer (score 1):

In everyday (or casual) use "time" is often (mis-)taken to mean

- duration, or
- a coordinate assignment to indications or entire events ("coordinate time").

In contrast, the current, correct and careful meaning of "time" in Physics is based on Einstein's definition of "time" as ["*the position of the little hand of my watch*"](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/On_the_Electrodynamics_of_Moving_Bodies_%281920_edition%29); i.e. generally as any one particular **[indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_%28distance_amplifying_instrument%29)** of any particular participant; or (also) as the entire ordered set of indications of any particular participant.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the three **primary** definitions of *time* in 3 prominent English language dictionaries:

> [American Heritage Dictionary](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=time) 
>   also [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/time) 
>   1a. A nonspatial continuum in which events occur in apparently irreversible succession from the past through the present to the future.
>   1b. An interval separating two points on this continuum; a duration:a long time since the last war; passed the time reading.
>   1c. A number, as of years, days, or minutes, representing such an interval:ran the course in a time just under four minutes.
>   1d. A similar number representing a specific point on this continuum, reckoned in hours and minutes:checked her watch and recorded the time, 6:17 AM.
>   1e. A system by which such intervals are measured or such numbers are reckoned:solar time.
>
> [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/timE) (also the same as in the Random House dictionary)
>   1a. the measured or measurable period during which an action, process, or condition exists or continues : duration 
>   1b. a nonspatial continuum that is measured in terms of events which succeed one another from past through present to future
>
> Oxford English Dictionary (from  Compact OED © 1971)
>   1. A limited stretch or space of continued existence, as the interval between two successive events or acts, or the period through which an action, condition, or state continues.

This is being used, by me, as an authoritative source so that this is simply no one's particular POV.  Being that these are general dictionaries, the only POV that you can accuse these definitions as having is the "English language" POV.  AH and OED live on opposite sides of the pond and MW is an old standard.

Now there are two grosser POVs to represent, and of one of these POVs, there are two sub-POVs to consider:

**Time as phenomenon or concept** like [space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space) or [spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime) or [cosmos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmos) or [life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life) or [consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consciousness) or [God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God) or some other "big idea" like that.

**Time as a quantity of measurement** like [length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length) or [mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass) or [electric charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_charge) or [temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature) or some "operational definition" like that.

**Of** the *operational* or *measurement* POV, there is another split.  Measurement with regard to **physical systems** (more objective) and measurement with respect to **experience** of a human or some other conscious being (more subjective, time being something we "feel").  The reason that these are two sides of the same coin is that all clocks or rulers or voltmeters are really just extensions of our senses or our experiential measurement of these quantities.  We gauge how big a bug is or another person or a building or a mountain, with respect to how big it appears alongside us.  We have an experiential measure of this quantity called *size* without a meter stick.  Similarly we have an experiential measure of time without external clocks.  But **both** our experience of this measurement or our usage of a measuring device (a clock) is acting on the same quantity.  It's just that our bare-handed biological, experiential measure might not be as tight as the one using a <sup>133</sup>**Cs** clock.

*Time as phenomenon* is a perspective that is both differentiated from the *Time as measurement* perspective and solidly supported by the English language dictionaries.  Leaving it out of the lede is not NPOV.  In addition, it is more fundamental.  During the first million years of the existence of the [Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe) there were certainly no sentient beings around to be experiencing or measuring time, but time existed.  There were physical processes going on that had quantitative relationships with each other and with time.  There was an $x(t)$  and there was a $t$, and no one was around measuring it.  Let's not get into any stupid *Tree-falling-in-the-forest-with-no-one-around-to-hear-it,-does-it-make-a-sound?* baloney.  Of course it did.  Time has been around a lot earlier than there had been anyone in the Universe measuring anything, including time.

Time is about the *existence* of things, about us and other things in the Universe.  The OED supports that.  Time is **apparently** unidirectional as we (and anything that is not an [antiparticle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiparticle) ) commonly experiences it.  In addition, it's single-dimensional (unlike space) so, the common understanding of time is that time *progresses* in one direction.    One *event* happens after another in an ordered *sequence* that can be placed on the [real number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) line.  Just like "greater than" > and "less than" < have meaning with real numbers, "earlier" or "previous"  and "later" or "subsequent" have comparable meaning with respect to *time*.

So, in two sentences, all three major POVs are comprehensively (not exhaustively) introduced.  We have *Time as phenomenon*, the fundamental definition, first with "past", "present" and "future".  This can be footnoted for a cutey and simple definition from John Wheeler: *"Time is what prevents everything from happening at once."* (along with *"Space is what prevents everything from happening to me."*)  Then we have *Time as measurement* or the "operational definition", both regarding the physical systems and regarding the human (or sentient) experience (we can measure the duration of something or we can guess how long it was from our experiencing it).  And we can footnote that with the statement from Einstein that *"Time is what clocks measure."*  Although not as comprehensive, both cited statements express, in a nutshell, what ''time'' is thought of fundamentally and what ''time'' is as a measurement.  They're good.

Also, *rate of change* of a quantity is directly related to and a consequence of *time*.  It is simply the [reciprocal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal) of time, $\frac{1}{t}$, or [frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency).  It belongs in the measurement sentence.  It is often how time is measured or experienced.

The more fundamental POV of time is that of Wheeler and the more operational POV is that of Einstein.  We can get the key concepts down with two concise sentences:

> **Time** is the indefinite continued [progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence) of [existence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existence) and [events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_(philosophy)) that occur in apparently [irreversible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreversible_process) succession from the [past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Past) through the [present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present) to the [future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future).  Time is a component quantity of various [measurements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurements) used to [sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence) events, to compare the durations of events or the intervals between them, and to [quantify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantification) [rates of change](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative) of quantities in [material reality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_realism) or in the [conscious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consciousness) [experience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualia).

Comment: just FYI, this is my part of a discussion we had long ago at Wikipedia as to what the lede intro sentences should be for the article [Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time).  i tried to get all of the basic (layman) stuff, the philosophical POV, and the pure physics POV in two sentences.  i thought i did well, but my suggestion was not accepted.

Comment: robert bristow-johnson: "_the statement from Einstein that "Time is what clocks measure."_" -- Actually, Einstein is [on record with: "_{for} ''time'' we substitute ''the position of the little hand of my watch''_"](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/On_the_Electrodynamics_of_Moving_Bodies_%281920_edition%29). That's decidedly **not referring to a measurement of duration**, but (merely) a pronouncement of appearance, or **indication**. This understanding of "time" by Einstein is thereby actually quite close to that of Wheeler ("You don't necessarily make all your observations at once"; IIHMS ...)